# Encoding the request body

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am using a simple form where a user can input some JSON.
I add that input to the body of the request.
When I retrieve the value from the body, it is not formatted/encoded as JSON.
Instead I get something like json=%7B%22vrt%22%3A%7B ...
How/where do I specify that the value in the body must be JSON in such way that my controller can parse it using GSON?

Thanks in advance.
Regards

The controller

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/sendMessage")
public ModelAndView sendIoTMessage(@RequestBody String json) {
    VehicleMessage vehicleMessage = new Gson().fromJson(json, VehicleMessage.class);
    MessageProcessor.postVehicleMessage(vehicleMessage);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("iot");
    return mav;
}
```

The form

```
<form id="sendMessage" th:action="@{/api/sendMessage}" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" th:value="*{json}" id="json" name="json">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Spring uses Jackson convertor for APPLICATION JSON, if you want to use GSON convertors, then you need to add GSONConvertor.

I personly perfer Option 1

Different ways to add GSONConvertor:

1. **Using JavaConfig**

   ```
   @Configuration @EnableWebMvc
   public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

   @Override
   public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter < ? >> converters) {
       GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
       converters.add(gsonHttpMessageConverter);
   }
   ```

   }
2. **Using customize converters**

   @Configuration
   public class CustomConfiguration {

   ```
   @Bean
   public HttpMessageConverters customConverters() {

       Collection<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();

       GsonHttpMessageConverter gsonHttpMessageConverter = new GsonHttpMessageConverter();
       messageConverters.add(gsonHttpMessageConverter);

       return new HttpMessageConverters(true, messageConverters);
   }
   ```

   }
3. **Using Auto-configuration** ..follow this [link](https://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/023-configure-integrate-gson-spring-boot/)

Comment: Using option 1 I get the following: Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Comment: By default GsonHttpMessageConverter doesnot support "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", it supports "application/json", If you want read request "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", then you need to create custon GSON convertor by extending GsonHttpMessageConverter and register that custom convertor with spring ..as explain in option 1

Answer (score 0):

Why not let Spring (de)serialize JSON for you? This functionality should work out of the box without any custom configuration.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/sendMessage", consumes="application/json")
public ModelAndView sendIoTMessage(@RequestBody VehicleMessage vehicleMessage) {
    MessageProcessor.postVehicleMessage(vehicleMessage);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("iot");
    return mav;
}
```